# Why doesn't the '?' regex character produce a match in sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a string similar to `../../sdd1` and trying to match `sdd` from here. I'm trying to use the following `sed` command:

```
echo "../../sdd1" | sed 's:.*\([a-z]\{3\}\)[0-9]?:\1:'
```

and it does not produce a match.
But when I use

```
echo "../../sdd1" | sed 's:.*\([a-z]\{3\}\)[0-9]\{0,1\}:\1:'
```

then I get my match, `sdd`.

My best guess is that I should escape the `?` as well, similar to the curly brackets - I tried it and it works, but I don't know why.

So the question is, why does the `[0-9]?` regex not match the `1` from `sdd1`, or why do we have to escape the `?` and the curly brackets?

Comment: See the `-E` switch, as well as the POSIX definitions of basic and extended regular expressions

Comment: since you've tagged ubuntu, I guess you are using GNU sed... see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE

Comment: thanks, I was suspecting something similar, `grep` has the same flags/usage.

Comment: pls add your reply as an answer

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/117549

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default, `sed` uses BRE and would need `-E` or `-r` option to use ERE

Quoting from [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE)

> In GNU sed the only difference between basic and extended regular expressions is in the behavior of a few special characters: ‘?’, ‘+’, parentheses, braces (‘{}’), and ‘|’.
>
> With basic (BRE) syntax, these characters do not have special meaning unless prefixed backslash (‘\’); While with extended (ERE) syntax it is reversed: these characters are special unless they are prefixed with backslash (‘\’).

so, for `GNU sed`, use

```
$ echo '../../sdd1' | sed 's:.*\([a-z]\{3\}\)[0-9]\?:\1:'
sdd
$ echo '../../sdd1' | sed -E 's:.*([a-z]{3})[0-9]?:\1:'
sdd
```

for [POSIX BRE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions), your second command is the way to go

```
$ echo '../../sdd1' | sed 's:.*\([a-z]\{3\}\)[0-9]\{0,1\}:\1:'
sdd
```