# grep for one or more occurrences of a word

Tags: grep

I want to search for the occurrence of type .
`super([A-Za-z]+ , self)`  in a codebase .

when I am going for 
`$ grep -nr '[s][u][p][e][r][(]' .` its showing me all the lines which has `super(` ,
when I tried to search for the below one with [A-Za-z]+ , I am not getting any result.Can someone please help me to search for all lines in my codebase which has `super(*word* , self)` in it.

```
anupam:codebase-2.0$ grep -nr '[s][u][p][e][r][(][A-Za-z]+' .
anupam:codebase-2.0$
```

Comment: Why are you using `[s][u][p][e][r][(]` instead of just `super(`? In any case, your regex is likely failing because you are using BRE and not escaping the `+`, i.e. you should use `\+`.

Comment: thanks a lot @Sparhawk , it worked just fine :)  doing $)grep -nr 'super([A-Za-z]\+'

Comment: No worries. I've written it out as a more complete answer.

Comment: assuming you have GNU grep, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375687/why-doesnt-the-regex-character-produce-a-match-in-sed otherwise see the question marked as duplicate for that question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, `grep` uses BRE (basic regular expressions), which means that special characters like `+` will be interpreted as a literal character. Hence, in GNU grep, it will need to be escaped, i.e. written as `\+`. (Alternatively, you could use ERE (extended regular expression), with the `-E` flag; see `man grep` for more information.) Hence, your command could be written like this:

```
grep -nr '[s][u][p][e][r][(][A-Za-z]\+'
```

In addition, the `[…]` surrounding each letter is unnecessary. `[…]` is used to specify a character class, e.g. `[ab]` could match to either `a` *or* `b`. If there is a single letter in the `[…]`, then that is the only match. Hence, your code could be simplified further to

```
grep -nr 'super([A-Za-z]\+'
```

N.B. As per [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas)'s [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471042/grep-for-one-or-more-occurrences-of-a-word/471064?noredirect=1#comment859699_471064), the `\+` construct is a GNU extension. If this doesn't work, you might try `\{1,\}` instead.

Comment: Note that in standard BREs, theb behaviour for `\+` is unspecified. `\+` is a GNU extension. The standard BRE equivalent of ERE `+` is `\{1,\}`.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas. I've updated my answer.

Comment: at least on my machine running Ubuntu 18, escaping is done with backslash `\+` not forward-slash `/+`

Comment: @FonsMA Oops, a typo (but just the first one). Thanks for the comment. Fixed!